# CoreData Migration from one-to-many to many-to-many

Tags: core-data, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have a problem in upgrading an old data model to a current model. It has a couple of layers which could be causing the problem and I'm struggling to determine where the issue lies.

I have an abstract Client entity which contains generic relationships to phone numbers, email addresses, etc. In my old model there was a relationship where a client could own 1 Property (but a Property could have many owners) or a client could be a tenant in a Lease (but a Lease can have many tenants). I've now updated the model such that a Client can own many Properties and be part of many Leases.

The concrete Client entities basically add different naming information to the abstract so there are Individual, Business, Government and Import (imported from other systems) subclasses.

My expectation was that the one-to-many relationship established in the old data model would be added as a first instance in a new many-to-many relationship in the new data model. Unfortunately the upgraded data store doesn't appear to contain any relationships in the new concrete clients for Properties or Leases.

The old model:

```
Client{
   Property<<-->Property.Owners
   Tenancy<<-->Lease.Tenants
}
ImportClient:Client{
   name:string
}
```

The new model:

```
Client{
  Properties<<-->>Property.Owners
  Tenancies<<-->>Lease.Tenants
}
ImportClient:Client{
  name:string
}
```

So now for the possible problems I can see. Firstly the relationship names have changed in the Client entity from Property to Properties and from Lease to Leases. So I've added a mapping model. The model didn't automatically add an Entity Mapping for ClientToClient (only for the concrete classes) so I've tried adding one myself. I'm not sure however how to set up the Value Expression so at the moment it's:

```
 FUNCTION($manager,"destinationInstancesForEntityMappingName:sourceInstances:","PropertyToProperty","$source.Property")
```

If I try and add the mapping to the concrete classes (so ImportClientToImportClient) it seems to be absolutely impossible to set the relationship values correctly (denied by the editor basically).

So my suspicions are that it's either failing to transfer the relationships because when the fetch is run against Client entity it returns nothing (whenever I've tried it this has been the case) or I'm just not getting the Value Expression right.

Help would be greatly appreciated because at the moment this is the only issue blocking the release of my major upgrade to the app.

Comment: You old and new data models are hard to understand described in a paragraph. You might want to include a screen shot or represent the entities in a text format as used in this previous answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788913/get-parent-child-array-from-coredata/6794413#6794413

Comment: I've given it a shot. Hopefully it makes more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution as I've found it (for those who stumble across this later...) in general terms as I don't have time at present to detail all the code here.

Step 1: See if you can open your data store without any migration options. If that succeeds continue on, otherwise Step 2.

Step 2: Retrieve the store metadata with [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistantStore...]

Step 3: Load your older models one at a time from most recent to oldest and use [NSManagedModel isConfiguration: compatibleWithStoreMetadata:] until you find a model that works

Step 4: Create a persistent store with the model that works and then create a managed object context from the data store and the persistent store

Step 5: Cache the failing relationship in a dictionary (I used pairs of UUIDs to identify the objects)

Step 6: Perform lightweight upgrade of the data store using your current managed object model

Step 7: Go through the dictionaries fetching the pairs of objects and associating them again

Yes you're going to have to use your own coding skills to implement this (it's about 250 lines of code for my instance) but hopefully this is the seed you need to get it working...